# Using sharepoint REST, how do I get item 10 to 19 only

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Below is my current URL, that I use to get all items in a list from my SharePoint site.

```
var dataUrl = "/web/lists/getbytitle('Blogmeddelelser')/items?&$select=EncodedAbsUrl,Id,Title,PublishedDate,Body,PostCategory/Title,PostCategory/Id,PostCategory/Title,Author/Title,Author/EMail,Author/Id&$expand=PostCategory/Id,Author/Id&Orderby=PublishedDate";
```

I was wondering if there is some way to add a "range" so It will only return item 10 to 19?

Comment: Are you asking about item IDs, or the 10th through 19th items in a list? If the former, you'll need to use two `$filter` criteria; if the latter, I would have said using `$top` with `$skip` was the annswer, but J.Doe's answer indicates you can't. So in your case, I'd suggest simply returning `$top=19` and ignoring the first 9 items.

Comment: @ChrisRomp I already had posted my answer when I noticed you suggested the same in your comment.  Definitely the way to go, I think, especially considering it's not a huge amount of items.

Comment: @DylanCristy No worries; I wasn't sure about it so I thought I'd clarify first here. :)

Answer (score 4):

Considering that you can't use `$skip` and that `$skiptoken` apparently uses the item ID, and taking into account that you are only asking for a very small number of items, why not just take the `$top=19` and slice off the first 9 in your receiving code?

```
var dataUrl = "/web/lists/getbytitle('Blogmeddelelser')/items?&$select=EncodedAbsUrl,Id,Title,PublishedDate,Body,PostCategory/Title,PostCategory/Id,PostCategory/Title,Author/Title,Author/EMail,Author/Id&$expand=PostCategory/Id,Author/Id&Orderby=PublishedDate&$top=19";
```

and then

```
var tenThroughNineteen = data.d.results.slice(9);
```

Comment: What if you're asking for the 1005th-1010th records? [wjervis's solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/234112/65896) looks more robust, and just as easy. What value does *top* have compared to a filter?

Comment: Well, that solution relies on the Item ID, so that solution kind of bypasses the OP's intent with the `OrderBy` part of the query.  wjervis's query says "get the items with ID 10 through 19, then order by Published Date", while I think the OPs intent was "take all the items, order by Published Date, then take the 10th through 19th of that new order."  You are right though, that if you wanted the 1005th - 1010th items, my solution is probably not optimal (though it would probably work).

Comment: And to answer your question about what value `$top` has, is that it allows you to do filtering and/or ordering, and then take just the first however many of the new result set, without needing any knowledge of the Item IDs involved.

Comment: Thanks! I was positive I must be missing something!

Comment: This is the best solution, imo.  `$skiptoken` would be better, but you'd have to know something about the 9 items you wanted to skip over to get to the 10th one.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the items with id between 10 and 19, you can use the `$filter` option:

```
$filter=ID ge 10 and ID le 19
```

With the URL you're currently using:

```
var dataUrl = "/web/lists/getbytitle('Blogmeddelelser')/items?$filter=ID ge 10 and ID le 19&$select=EncodedAbsUrl,Id,Title,PublishedDate,Body,PostCategory/Title,PostCategory/Id,PostCategory/Title,Author/Title,Author/EMail,Author/Id&$expand=PostCategory/Id,Author/Id&Orderby=PublishedDate";
```

More on `$filter` can be found [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35796.sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-for-selecting-filtering-sorting-and-pagination-in-sharepoint-list.aspx#Filtering_items).

Comment: Is there a way to filter items by the order they're returned in? (Keep the 10th-19th items in the given sort order?)

Answer (score 0):

You can you the skip token from rest api to get items from list as you desired.
But make sure that the items must not deleted from the list or the range may vary the list item id. For example

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Blogmeddelelser')/items?$skiptoken=Paged=TRUE&p_ID=10&$top=9
```

here p_ID is last item ID you want from the list and $ top is the limit of items you want.And it is maily used for paging in SharePoint.

Comment: Well if i have to add an Id to the code then i don't feel its so dynamic is it?

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic i didn't. But asking to get 9 items.
And if i am not wrong you asking for the next iteration records. if yes you get the next skip token from the rest itself you can reuse it

Comment: You say " p_ID is last item ID" ! if i add a new list item, then i would have to update the code, if i have to get the 10 to 19 items of the newest,

Comment: I didn't mean it to be the last item of list infact it is the last item from which you want the items should be get as a range. As you specified the range i took it 10 - 19 , its your wish you can start it with 0 - 10

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Blogmeddelelser')/items?$skip=10&$top=9
```

but I think that only works on lists themselves and not individual list items

Edit:

Looks like the only way to get `$skip` functionality on list items is to use `__next`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964936/using-skip-with-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api